# What exactly is the issue between Shankaracharya of Dwarka peeth and the Sai Trust?

Tags: worship, sai

I just need one simple answer, "[Is Sai Baba of Shirdi really a God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3445/2995) [closed]" and, if he is, then why is Swami Swaroopanand Saraswati (Shankaracharya of Dwarka peeth) having an issue with worshiping Sai Baba? If Sai Baba is not a God, then why has the Swami waited for at least 50 years to say this?

And in Sanatana Dharma do we have any restriction on who we can worship or can we worship any one (such as Sai Baba)?

Comment: One can do this: Please answer these two questions "Who really are You?" and "Who really is God?". If once one have answered (or even better realized the answers) to these two questions (actually if one know the answer to one question then one will know the answer to the second one) one will get a better idea of "is X God?" or "is Y God?". Any answers that one can and will get here will only be opinions of everyone.

Comment: As for question about Shankaracharya. This is an age-old question. Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, Sri Ramakrishna Paramhansa, Sri Sai Baba. all of these saints are regarded as incarnations by their followers. The followers claim there is great evidence that supports them while the detractors claim there isn't enough of an evidence to support it. This is the most common suggested route: if you want to follow please follow. if you do not then please do not criticize also. Respect the beliefs of others and carry on in one's own path. This is being Hindu Sir :). All d best.

Comment: I follow Sai BABA n every alternate month I go to Shirdi as well. However, I just wanted to know that why he is creating issues (Shankara Charya). Being hindu I always want that our must religion grow, but if something like this happens, it impacts us and our Sanatan Dharam as well.

Comment: Aspire for direct experience always. Once you have tasted sugar and know that it is indeed sweet, then no scripture or any other authority can convince you that sugar is spicy isn't it? Similarly once you have experienced the Divinity in Sri Sai Baba (Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and Sri Ramakrishna or any other God-realized Saint) directly for yourself, then no-one else will be able to convince you otherwise. Shankaracharya is presenting His views on the matter. The devotees of Sai Baba (and other great saints) have directly experienced His divinity, therefore they will not swerve from their path

Comment: As for "Why Shankaracharya is telling like this" analogy: Each person understands the Truth in His own way. A person who looks at the elephant from the side describes it as "it looks like a giant leg". The person who looks at it from front describes it as "it looks like a giant head". Both are fighting saying 'you are wrong, for I have seen the elephant, so I am right and you are not!'. But the wise man looks at both angles and concludes 'it looks like a leg from the side, and a head from front! both are right, and both are not full without the other'. Taken from Sri Ramakrishna's teaching

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/829/what-is-the-basis-for-worshipping-sai-baba-are-there-are-references-to-him-in-t/3607#3607