# What is the source of the Sanskrit śloka that lists the four corner-stones of dharma?

Tags: mahabharata, scripture, dharma, manu-smriti

> Vedah Smritah Sadaachaarah Svasyacha priyamaatmanah, 
>   Etad chaturvidham praahuh saakshaat Dharmasya lakshanam
>
> The four corner-stones of Dharma are Veda, Smriti, Sadaachaara and above all,
>   one's own Inner Conscience.

The above Sanskrit śloka can be found at the end of [this book](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Dharma%20Bindu.pdf) (Dharma Bindu - Essence of Dharma Shastra).

What is the source of this śloka? Which scripture contains this?

> yaś **caturguṇasaṃpannaṃ** dharmaṃ veda sa dharmavit
>   aher iva hi dharmasya padaṃ duḥkhaṃ gaveṣitum [[MB, Shanti Parva, 12-130.019a](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_12_u.htm)]

Above, Bhishma seems to make an indirect reference to it in the Mahabharata and that reference has been used in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/832/2995) answer.

Comment: A very similar sloka with almost the same purport is found in the Yajnavalkya Smriti :http://i.stack.imgur.com/jrsKD.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Shloka is available in [Manu Smriti, Chapter 2, Verse 12](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145585.html).

> वेदः स्मृतिः सदाचारः स्वस्य च प्रियमात्मनः ।
>
> एतच्चतुर्विधं प्राहुः साक्षाद् धर्मस्य लक्षणम् ॥ १२ ॥
>
> vedaḥ smṛtiḥ sadācāraḥ svasya ca priyamātmanaḥ |
>
> etaccaturvidhaṃ prāhuḥ sākṣād dharmasya lakṣaṇam || 12 ||
>
> The Veda, the Smṛti, the Practice of cultured Men, and what is agreeable to oneself—these directly constitute the fourfold means of knowing Dharma.—(12)

Comment: @sv. Thanks for the link. Actually I was searching for the good version of Manu Smriti.

Answer (score 0):

This Shloka is also found in at-least two Puranas, besides other scriptures.

### 1. Bhavishya Purana:

- Verse 57, Chapter 7, Part 1 (Brahma Khanda).

> [Chapter 7](https://archive.org/details/BhavishyaPuranPart1/Bhavishya%20Puran%20Part%201%20/page/n101/mode/2up) - Brahma Parva, Bhavishya Purana
>
> वेदः स्मृतिः सदाचारः स्वस्य च प्रियमात्मनः ।
>  एतच्चतुर्विधं विप्राः
> साक्षाद्धर्मस्य लक्षणम् ॥ ५७ ॥
>
> Meaning:
>
> > Vedas, smritis, suitable (approved) tradition, and what is agreeable to one's conscience, the wise have declared to be the four direct pieces of evidence of *dharma*.

This verse is exactly similar to that asked in the question

---

### 2. Vishnu-Dharmottara Purana

- Verse 63, Chapter 233, Part 3

> [Chapter 233](https://archive.org/details/9000000004657SriVishnuDharmottaraMahapuranam1000pSANSKRIT1929/page/n857/mode/2up?view=theater), Tritiya Khanda, Vishnudharmottara Purana
>
> वेदः स्मृतिः सदाचारः स्वस्य च प्रियमात्मनः ।
>  एतच्चतुर्विधं प्राहुः
> साधूनां धर्मलक्षणम्  ॥ ६३ ॥

Here, the second line of the verse is a bit different from the original one.
Instead of `साक्षाद्धर्मस्य लक्षणम्` we have `साधूनां धर्मलक्षणम्`

---

**On a side Note:**

As already said by one of the users in the [comments](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/what-is-the-source-of-the-sanskrit-%C5%9Bloka-that-lists-the-four-corner-stones-of-dh#comment37099_15093), a similar verse is also found in the Yajnavalkya Smriti

> [Verse 7](https://archive.org/details/YajnavalkyaSmritiKashiSktGranthamala178HindiTikaUmeshChandraPandeyChowkhambaSanskritSansthan/page/n59/mode/2up), Chapter 1, Yajnavalkya Smriti
>
> श्रुतिः स्मृतिः सदाचारः स्खस्य च प्रियमात्मनः ।
>  सम्यक्संकल्पजः कामो
> धर्ममूलमिदं स्मृतम् ॥ ७ ॥
>
> > VII. — The Sruti, the Smiriti, the conduct of good men, what appears
> > pleasant to one's own self, and the desire that springs from a good
> > resolution, is said to be the root of Dharma.

<sup>One may access the English Translation along with the commentary of Vijnanevara called the *Mitaksara* [from here](https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj/page/12/mode/2up?view=theater)</sup>