# From where do priests get invocation(Avahana) and other Mantras related to Shirdi Sai Baba?

Tags: scripture, worship, mantras, sai

From where ( which **Hindu Scripture**) do Hindu priests get Mantras related to [Sai Baba's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sai_Baba_of_Shirdi) worship?

Like invocation(Avahana) & other Mantras?

This question is relevant because Sai Baba is **ritualistically** worshiped in many Hindu Temples of India and elsewhere very much like other Vedic Deities.

And the first step in a Hindu Puja is **Avahana** or invocation of the Deity .

Now, since Sai Baba is not mentioned in any Scriptures ,how are the priests getting Mantras needed for his worship in temples?

Are they **manufacturing** Mantras ?

Please note that i'm only talking about Mantras that are needed for **ritualistic** Puja & not about prayers and other mental ways of worship.

Also,i don't see my question as duplicate of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/829/what-is-the-basis-for-worshipping-sai-baba-are-there-are-references-to-him-in-t) question.Because i'm specifically asking about Hindu Scriptures that contain Mantras related to Sai's worship .

My question is not about whether he should be worshiped or not.

Please also note  that this is not about **demeaning** any religious figure nor about **challenging** one's faith.

I'm just **curious** to know how are the priests getting the needed Mantras,that's all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Shirdi Sai is not Hindu/Vedic god. So the Question is not about hinduism. Obviously they are manufacturing the Mantras like they manufactured Sai Gyatri.

Comment: @Yogi It's not off-topic. Sai Baba questions are definitely on topic for this site. There are different theories of Sai Baba being avatar of Dattatreya and/or Shiva. So, it's up to the individual to believe it, though Sai is not mentioned in Puranas. Again, this is personal. My point here is to say Sai questions are on topic. If you feel this as off topic, post question on meta, we will discuss there. :)

Comment: I think sai Baba himself has given one mantra to devotees "Shradha & Saburi" No spicial mantras are sung in temples of sai Baba , but people from all religions visit temples , and generally Guru Mantras & Aarti is sung in temples.But one can worship him by other worship mantras from their own language etc.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar We can see idols of Sai in his temples.Do u mean to say that these idols did not go through "Prana Prathistha" ceremonies!?

Comment: @Rickross - They do go through Pranaprathisthapana and during daily puja general puja vidhi and mantras also used. Although i am not devotee but have seen puja in Many sai temples.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Ok.Then ,that is precisely my question.From which scripture they are obtaining those Pranapratishta mantras.

Comment: @Rickross I think they themselves make mantras believing every letter to be Sabda Brahman..

Comment: @Rickross--Pujya Narasimaha swami of Chennai wandered in search of a guru and at last he found in Shirdi in 1946. His wandering stopped. At that time Sai was not there. Sai attained Samadhi in the year 1918. Pujya Narasimaha swami composed ashtotra for shirdi sai. The arthis [ 4 times a day] is in Marathi and it was during sau's time  [1835-1918].He is considered as kaliyug avatar. I am a devotee and had more than 35 experiences from sadguru. Life history of Sai Baba by Amulya Samabasiva rao states he is avatar of Lord Shva.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Here is the question on Meta Hinduism SE http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/636/489.